# How do I run a check on a user's account every time they login using Devise in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Devise, and when someone logs in I would like to execute a custom method.

Similarly to how you use `before_save` to execute a method before the account/model is updated/saved, or `before_create` to do the same before the object is initially created.

I would like to do the same, but for users logging in.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `application_controller.rb` add the following code:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    execute_custom_function()
    super
  end
```

You can utilize [Devise's Controller Helper](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#after_sign_in_path_for-instance_method).

Comment: I tried this Mike: `if (current_user.has_trial_expired?) redirect_to(:settings)`, but now I am getting an error: `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Devise/sessionsController#create

Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".`

Thoughts on what could be causing this ?

Comment: This is because this method expects you to return a route, but you are redirecting and the code calling this method is also redirecting. If you look at the linked example, you can see how they are accessing the user object that is being passed. I would highly suggest doing something like that.

Comment: So you would probably want: if resource.is_a?(User) && resource.hash_trial_expired?
    settings_path

Comment: Well...just adding `return url_for(:settings)` worked. But I will try your other suggestions.

Comment: Btw, your solution worked too...I guess it's better, in the event I am using devise in the future for a model other than User. So I am keeping it. Thanks :)